# can I download public dataset in bigquery to local computer if I don't pay the bill in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to download the public dataset from bigquery but I don't know how to download it. I cannot make bucket because I dont pay the GCP bill. Is it possible to download public dataset from bigquery to local computer if I dont pay the bill? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data in the public dataset you're trying to access you could use the BigQuery sandbox, if you do not have an associated billing account, or a billing account enabled project.  The goal would be to keep it under 1 TB in processing.

Once your query, you can either run it in the UI and download directly to your local machine if the data volume is small enough, or write a script using one of the supported client libraries and extract it locally that way.

For more information on the sandbox:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox